# Python 3 - Get an input to be a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this input to become a function to use later on when buying/selling shares in a program. Is this possible? For example, later on I might do:

if shareOne >= 50 //where >= is shareQuestionBuy or shareQuestionSell

### CODE BELOW

```
#Input of share code
shareCode = str(input("What is your share code? "))
if isValid(shareCode):
    print("\nShare code", str(shareCode), "is valid\n")
else:
    print("\nERROR! Share code", str(shareCode), " invalid. Share code too short/long or contains alpha/unicode characters.\n Program will now terminate\n")
    quit()


shareQuestionBuy = bool(input("Are shares bought by" + str(shareCode) + "bought when they are below the limit price (True) or greater than/equal to the limit price (False)? (True/False only): "))
if shareQuestionBuy == True:
    print("Shares will now only be bought if they are below the limit price")
    shareQuestionBuy = <
elif shareQuestionBuy == False:
    print("Shares will now only be bought if they are greater than/equal to the limit price")
    shareQuestionBuy = <=
```

Comment: FYI, the value of an `input()` is already a string, so you don't need to call `str(input(...`, and you certainly don't need to keep calling `str(shareCode)` every time you want to print it. String concatenation works seamlessly with `str1 + " some text " + str2`.

Comment: Your example code is quite unclear - for example, why is `shareQuestionBuy` redefined, starting as a boolean and then becoming an operator? And is the question about inputs as the title says, or just about assigning an operator to a value as the body implies? If you can cut down the question to the essential point you are asking about it would be a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

[`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```
3>> import operator
3>> foo = operator.gt
3>> foo(3, 2)
True
```

Comment: Cheers, how does this get implemented into the code though?

Comment: Erm... `shareQuestionBuy = operator.lt` ... `shareQuestionBuy(something, somethingElse)`